# Setting reducer type in cascading

Tags: hadoop, cascading

How would you set different type of reducers in cascading for output for HadoopFlowConnector? In all tutorials we only see the default TextDelimited being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am little confused by the terms reducer and output which you have used here. If you are asking what else we can use in place of TextDelimited while sinking the output in cascading then I can say that : TextDelimited is a type of Scheme in cascading and other schemes which are present SequenceFile, TextLine, AvroScheme. You can use one as per your data and requirement. By using any of these scheme you can make your Tap and connect the tail of output to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that was a poorly worded question.